# Short == realization

Tags: haskell

I have a simple type

```
data Day =  Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
```

I'm a newbie in haskell, so I write `==` as follows.

```
(==) :: Day -> Day -> Bool
Monday == Monday = True
Tuesday == Tuesday = True
Wednesday == Wednesday = True
...
x == y = False
```

Is there any shorter way to write `==` realization?

Comment: why would you write this, and why wouldn't you simply use = instead of ==?  You could define == as =, but that would also be quite strange.

Comment: Try writing what you're thinking of Kristopher. You'll see why it won't work

Comment: If you are really using that for manipulating days you can use `Data.Time.Calendar` and `Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate` instead of defining your own data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the compiler to autogenerate these by using the `deriving` keyword:

```
data Day = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
           deriving Eq
```

This will define both `==` and `/=` for your datatype.

"Eq may be derived for any datatype whose constituents are also instances of Eq." http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Eq.html

Answer (score 6):

You can write

```
data Day =  Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday
  deriving Eq
```

Which will mean that GHC will automatically generate an instance of Eq for Day.
It will generate (==) such that `Monday == Monday`, `Tuesday == Tuesday` is `True` etc, but `Monday == Friday` is `False`

Note that you can't write something like

```
(==) :: Day -> Day -> Bool
x == x = True
x == y = False
```

which is perhaps what you were thinking of.

If you try, GHC will complain about conflicting definitions for x.